# edit operating system directory file

Tags: windows, file, operating-system, filesystems

**Files**
I learned from school that operating system deal with directory as file and it contains elements like list of files in the directory and extension of its

***so how could I open and edit that file in windows for example?***

Answer (score 0):

The operating system does not know exactly how files and directories are stored, only the driver/code for a specific filesystem (ntfs, fat, ext4, btrfs, zfs etc.) knows that.

When you create and delete files like normal you are essentially modifying the "directory file". There is no generic way to edit a directory directly, you have to use normal directory and file functions provided by the OS.

Technically it might be possible to get raw access to the disk and play with the raw bytes but if you do this on a live system you are most likely just going to corrupt it.